# Stray Voxels after mesh Voxelization using Pyvista

Tags: python, voxel, pyvista

I've been playing around with the Threejs BufferGeometry and Pyvista.

I was able to export it to Pyvista, the visualization of the mesh works just perfectly :

[Normal Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypDUN.png)

but I when I voxalize it, It gets some weird stray voxles all around the 3D Scene :

[Voxelized Mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRuDi.png)

Did any one faced this kind of issues or knows to fix this kind of issue ?

Thank you in advance.

tried meshfix, connectivity and lowering the Pyvista Voxelization density value but It didn't change much.

EDIT :

The used code :

```
mesh = pv.read("test2.stl")

p.add_mesh(mesh, color="lightblue", opacity=0.5)

voxels = pv.voxelize(
    mesh.triangulate(), density=mesh.length / 300, check_surface=False
).connectivity()


p.add_mesh(voxels, color=True, show_edges=True, opacity=1)

p.enable_anti_aliasing("ssaa")
p.export_obj("voxeled.obj")
p.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These artifacts remind me of [this PyVista issue](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues/1743). I found a workaround for (potentially *some* of these stray pixels) by triangulating the mesh before voxelization. [We made triangulation before voxelization automatic](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/pull/3361), this was added for PyVista release 0.37.0, released November 2022.

So if you're using a PyVista version older than 0.37.0, either manually triangulate your mesh with `mesh.triangulate().voxelize()`, or update your PyVista version. If you're already on a more recent version then the issue is unrelated.

Comment: The version I'm using is 0.36.1, I do face this issue only while trying to voxelize buildings with gaps.. 

I tried the `triangulate()` the `connectivity()` looks like nothing is working !

Comment: @Sofiane just to cover the simplest mistake: did you directly use the triangulated mesh for voxelization like I showed, e.g. `mesh.triangulate().voxelize()`? It would be best if you updated your question with the code that doesn't work. We can't debug code we can't see.